# visual studio warning: (ESLint) Failed to load config "defaults/configurations/eslint" to extend from. Referenced from C:\Users\{username}\.eslintrc

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, import, eslint

In Visual Studio 2019 Community ver. 16.5.4 there are warnings displayed for typescript files with import and export declarations.

[image: 'Error List' tab, warning]

[image: annotation in editor window for a typescript file:]

Warnings are not shown if files are not opened. But when I open a typescript file, then warning apears.

It is a starter template of angular 9. I added to it a few packages (bootstrap, jwt-decode, fontawesome, jquery, popper.js)

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio's ESLinter is attempting to load a global config file that is referenced in *C:\Users\Adam* - go there and look for a file named `.eslintrc`. You may remove it.

After you remove it I believe VS will use it's default ESLint config and you may see warnings that apply to Typescript but don't really make sense in the context of Angular.

If you want to disable ESLint entirely for that project in VS:

1. Navigate to **Tools** > **Options**
2. Select **Text Editor** on left pane
3. Expand **JavaScript/TypeScript**
4. Select **Linting** > **General**
5. Uncheck **Enable ESLint**

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Tools > Options
2. Select Text Editor on left pane
3. Expand JavaScript/TypeScript
4. Select Linting > General
5. Click Reset Global .eslintrc button
6. click OK